# how to block Sudo for a specific application/service

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, administrator

As an admin, I'm looking to see if there is a way for me to set limitations on the Linux devices we use for development. (i.e)- I want to give my users SUDO access / the ability to use sudo IF needed, But they can't Start or Stop running background applications.

example: we have crowd strike running and don't want the user to start and stop it when they want

Similar to how I can have Admin Access to users in Windows but can restrict what they can use admin access for And is there a way to get logs of what they use the Sudo command on?

I have not tried anything except creating a VM with Linux and creating a guest account but some codes need SUDO command so I gave the account sudo access

Comment: What research have you done? SUDO means a certain thing: full control. If you want to grant some control but not all, you probably don't want them to be able to SUDO, and will need to use some other means to grant them the permissions they DO need.

Comment: We want them to be able to use sudo so that they can install applications and do updates just not start and stop the running services. Any alternatives would be appreciated.

Comment: sudo = superuser do. You can't alter on which programs it can be called and in which it cannot. You might however look into giving them permissions for whatever they will need to read/write/execute (so they won't need sudo).

Comment: ok how about this is there a command on the local admin level thats not super user like sudo?